# Prevent Excel document being overwritten

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I am creating Excel reports for clients to enable multi users to pull in data relevant to their sector of the business and am exploring options to protect the documents from being overwritten whilst still allowing macros to run and the document to be edited.

Googling gives three commonly suggested ways to do this:

1) Password protect the file when saving so that regular users cannot save over the original file

- **Pro:** does not require vba, no version control issues
- **Con:** Risk of forgetting password, pop-up could be considered    annoying for users

2) Create a workbook_beforesave event which prevents the original file being overwritten

- **Pro:** no pop-up / invisible to users, no version control issues
- **Con:** if project is password then risk of password being forgotten, requires vba which could put off some people

3) Saving file as .xltm (template) which forces user to save as a new document rather than overwrite

- **Pro:** no pop-up / invisible to users, no password issues, does not require vba
- **Con:** changes would be have to be done in the original file and then re-saved as template so might cause version control issues.

Are there any other options or further pros/cons to be considered for each of the suggested options?

Comment: I suggust set read only to the file

Comment: Thanks pokemon_man, Nick has suggested the same and I think you are both right. Can you think of what circumstances may require one of the more complex options I mentioned? Want to check I am not missing anything.

Comment: If your workbook is a template where users work off of then i suggest worksheet password protect therefore user cannot change anything on worksheet other then the areas needed to be change. Then set workbook as read only therefore they cannot save over the file thus having to save as another workbook name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about saving the document as Read-only? That way they can't save over the original.

To do so File > Save as and then next to the save button click the tools button as shown, then general options and check the Read only box as shown in the next image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nick, that actually looks to suit my needs exactly, slightly embarrassed that I did not think that and was trying to over-complicate things. Before closing it off though, can you think of what circumstances may require one of the more complex options I mentioned? Want to check I am not missing anything.

Comment: Just keeping track of updates etc, but that will be common to all the options.

Comment: @SolarMike took the words out of my mouth :)